# jquery image upload in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, file-upload

I am looking for an Image upload from the client side.
So I tried with the following tutorial and its worked amazing with Firefox and Chrome.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

But it didnt worked with IE9 as it doesnt support the APIs. Very painful Browser :'(

So I looked for other plugin,I found out the following website:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

But they mentioned it will work for Java, but I dont know how to implement it as he has written code in php, which I dont required.If anyone helps me how to implement that plugin using Java. I need anykind of solution which helps me,Please help me anyone.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

That site states that it `Works with any server-side platform that supports standard HTML form file uploads`.  In Java this is commonly solved using [Commons Fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/), a well documented and fairly easy to use library.

EDIT: actually a very detailed overview using Commons FileUpload but also the built-in fileupload support from Servlet 3.0 can be found [right here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)